# boost mpl lower_bound at runtime

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, metaprogramming

In the code below I have a class `SizedFoo` which is constructed for a specific size. The class `GeneralFoo` holds an array of `SizedFoos` of different sizes and then the function `Bar` will find the `SizedFoo` which is initialized for the smallest size larger than the passed in parameter. I know boost mpl has the lower_bound function but that can only be used with a statically known value, is there any way to use an equivalent at runtime?

```
class SizedFoo {
  ...
public:
  SizedFoo(size_t size);
  void Bar();
}

template<size_t... sizes_in>
class GeneralFoo {
  typedef vector_c<size_t, sizes_in...>::type raw_sizes;
  typedef sort<raw_sizes>::type sorted_raw_sizes;
  typedef unique<sorted_raw_vector, equal_to<_1, _2> >::type sizes;

  std::array<SizedFoos*, size<sizes>::type> foos_;
public:
  GeneralFoo() {
    ...
  }
  void Bar(size_t size) {
    //DOESN'T WORK: size is a runtime value
    //auto index = lower_bound<sizes, size>::type;
    auto index = ... //What goes here?
    foos_[index]->Bar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mpl is compile time - what you are trying to achieve can only be done at runtime, for that you will need to use `std::lower_bound()`.